# How can I get the file's total size without content-length

Tags: ios, download, content-length

I want to download some files and show the downloading progress with progressview. The format is currentSize/totalSize. As you know, I can get the total size using content-length of http response. However, sometimes you cannot find the attribute in headers.
  So, my question is how can I get the total size of file to be download? Or is there any way to make content-length reappear in headers.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLResponse` has a method called `-(long long)expectedContentLength`
It returns the expected content length or `NSURLResponseUnknownLength` if the length can't be determined.

Source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresponse/1413507-expectedcontentlength)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it try [response expectedContentLength] and get -1. Any other good idea?

Comment: Well NSURLResponseUnknownLength is equal to -1. At what point do you call it? Are using NSURLConnection?

Comment: i call it in - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

Comment: Yes that's the place to get it! It means that your response knows nothing about the content length. Do you have an idea about the length of the files? (for example : all images from 200Kb to 500Kb )

Comment: the size of file to be download is less than 100Kb

Comment: If you're sure all your files are less than 100Kb you could pretend that it's the expected value. It's not totally honest to the user but it will give them an approximate idea of the progress. You can even check each time that you append the data that the overall data is not over 100kb and if it is, just increment the expected by 5 for example. It will seem as if the network got slower. At the end of the loading set your current length to the expected length (manually).